# php js mysql dropdown selection fills textboxes with db value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

Dear stackoverflow users, I am banging my head for a piece of code that can't be too difficult but somehow my brain is not working today, so please help.

I am creating a form where I want to select an id from a drop down (this is working), and after selection I want to see all the records related to the id in textfields. I want to create the fields manually so I don't want an autocreate script. This is the code i have so far:

```
 <!--Onderstaande gegevens worden NIET geprint!-->
 <div id="non-printable">
 <!---->
 <?
 // Load Joomla! configuration file
 require_once('configuration.php');
 // Create a JConfig object
 $config = new JConfig();
 // Get the required codes from the configuration file
 $server    = $config->host;
 $username  = $config->user;
 $password  = $config->password;
 $database = $config->db;
 // Tools dropdown
 $con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
 mysql_select_db($database);
 $sql = "SELECT cb_dealerid FROM cypg8_comprofiler";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 // Dealergegevens fields

 ?>
  <!--Begin TOOLS--> 
  <div class="tools">
   <div class="dealerselectie">
    <?
    echo "<select name='cb_dealerid'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "'>" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
?>   
</div><!--/.Dealerselectie-->
  </div><!--/.Tools-->
  <!--Einde TOOLS-->
  <!--Begin DEALERGEGEVENS-->
  <div class="dealergegevens">
     <input type="text" name="cb_dealerid" value='" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "'><br>
    <input type="text" name="cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam" value='" . $row['cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam'] . "'>  

  </div><!--/.dealergegevens--> 
  <!--Einde DEALERGEGEVENS--> 
 </div><!--/#non-printable-->
 <!--Bovenstaande gegevens worden NIET geprint!-->
```

I know I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is. I need to create this without using a multipage form so it all needs to stay on one page. Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I keep on trying to get it to work obviously and this is one of the attempts which is also not working.

```
   <?echo "<input type=\"text\" value='" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "'>";?>
<?echo "<input type=\"text\" value='" . $row['cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam'] . "'>";?>
```

EDIT 2: <== MORE INFORMATION ABOUT WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE

I have in my database table the following details

```
cb_dealerid = 100, 101, 102, 103
cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam = willem, henk, piet, klaas
```

When i select in the dropdown id 101 i want to see in the textbox the name henk.

EDIT 3:

I know have 2 files `html.php` and `get_user_details.php`:

HTML.php:

```
 <?
 // Load Joomla! configuration file
 require_once('configuration.php');
 // Create a JConfig object
 $config = new JConfig();
 // Get the required codes from the configuration file
 $server    = $config->host;
 $username  = $config->user;
 $password  = $config->password;
 $database = $config->db;
 // Tools dropdown
 $con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
 mysql_select_db($database);
 $sql = "SELECT cb_dealerid FROM cypg8_comprofiler";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 ?>
 <?
 echo "<select name='cb_dealerid' id='user_ids' onchange='user_details(this.value)'>";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value='" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "'>" . $row['cb_dealerid'] . "     </option>";
}
 echo "</select>";
 ?>
 <input type="text" name="cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam" id="cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam" >
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function user_details(id)
 { 
 $.get('get_user_details.php', {user_id:id}, // Response file get_user_details.php.      This file is to bring all details against the id you selected from dropdown.. Make a JSON form by encode function.
 function(data) 
   {
       var jsonArr   = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // here you received your JSON data
       var username  = jsonArr.user_name; // Now this variable user_name is the Array Index      Name which you defined in your response file.
  $('#Name').val(username); // Now assign this value to a textfield with ID Name.
  });
}
```

get_user_details.php

```
 <?
 $User_Array = array($_GET['cb_dealerid']); // Just an example. You need to fetch data      properly by $_GET['user_id'];
 echo json_encode($User_Array); // You can check this response in your Console.
 ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_query. Instead look into PDO or even ADODB.

Comment: I can't guess what you want to do.

Comment: I have just added some more info to the original question. Thanks for your answer. Bye the way i have no idea what PDO or ADODB is. And i believe that it is possible by mysql.

Comment: mysql_query is not secure and deprecated.

Comment: As for what you want to do, look up jquery.org and $.post in google.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code. use it your way.

First of all call a function: Like this :

// This is the Drop Down

```
<select name="user_ids" id="user_ids" onchange="user_details(this.value)">
```

// U need a texfield to show any single attribute of selected Id

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" >
```

// U need a response file: In code below its: get_user_details.php

```
$User_Array = array('user_name'=>Necromancer); // Just an example. You need to fetch data properly by $_GET['user_id'];

echo json_encode($User_Array); // You can check this response in your Console.
```

Here is Ur JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function user_details(id)
{ 


        $.get('get_user_details.php', {user_id:id}, // Response file get_user_details.php. This file is to bring all details against the id you selected from dropdown.. Make a JSON form by encode function.


        function(data) 
        {

            var jsonArr   = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // here you received your JSON data
                        var username  = jsonArr.user_name; // Now this varaible user_name is the Array Index Name which you defined in your response file.

                        $('#Name').val(username); // Now assign this value to a textfield with ID Name.





        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried implementing what you said but I am doing something wrong i believe I have created 2 jsfiddle pages one for the html page and the other for the get user details page. Please take a look at them [link]http://jsfiddle.net/zHzB9/1/ [link]http://jsfiddle.net/yb6vT/

Comment: Yes I know I have tried following the tutorial from W3Schools(http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) and this is basically doing what i want but when i change the details to the details from my server/databse it stops working.

Comment: You need to debug your code. put alerts in function. Check that if your function is called or not. Is it bringing Data or not.

Comment: The example code you have given me. I think i am using it wrong you say that I need to learn more about Jquery. I dont see any jquery in your code(It properly is there but i dont recognize it). I appreciate all the help from you but is there a way that you can show me what to copy/paste and into which file. basically a step by step. When i have one textfield working I know i can get all the others added by myself. I have been looking at a lot of tutorials today and most of them are inconclusive even the ones from w3schools . I can understand if you dont want to do 'my' job but i hope you help.

Comment: I had no room left! I have no idea where to put the alerts. I have copy pasted the codes you provided into 2 files because that is what i thought i should do and I will update above what those 2 files are now. It is under EDIT 3

Comment: Yea you must add Latest JQuery Library to Run any Jquery Code. Otherwise it wont work.

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: i have added this script in html.php didnt work. i have added it in get_user_details.php didnt work. added to both didnt work. please is it possible for anyone to give me a full piece of code that i can copy and paste. because with all the changes over the last couple of hours i dont even know if the basic setup is correct. so pretty please with 2 kilo of cream on top. write the entire code. I know it is a lot to ask but with all the time this has cost i think it would be faster. thanks in advance i appreciate all the help i am already getting.

Comment: I have already provided you the exact piece of code. Now you just have to place it in your own order. Please check if there is some error in your console. Let me know what are they.